# Is it possible to exclude SIM contacts when using Intent.ACTION_PICK?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I need to pick contacts in my app and would like to exclude those which are stored in my SIM card. Is it possible with `ACTION_PICK`?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651609/how-to-display-phone-contacts-only-exclude-sim-contacts

Comment: You should use ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI to query and display them in a ListView youself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, it's not possible

Unfortunately, it's **not** possible for now.

To proof it, let's dive into **source code of [`ContanctsListActivity`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.7_r1/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java)**.
[Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.7_r1/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java#561) an `onCreate()` method of the `Activity`. In it, ContactApp reads `Intent`(`ACTION_PICK`) we passing to it and handles it respectively:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    mIconSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
    mContactsPrefs = new ContactsPreferences(this);
    mPhotoLoader = new ContactPhotoLoader(this, R.drawable.ic_contact_list_picture);

    // Resolve the intent
    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    // Allow the title to be set to a custom String using an extra on the intent
    String title = intent.getStringExtra(UI.TITLE_EXTRA_KEY);
    if (title != null) {
        setTitle(title);
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    String component = intent.getComponent().getClassName();

    // When we get a FILTER_CONTACTS_ACTION, it represents search in the context
    // of some other action. Let's retrieve the original action to provide proper
    // context for the search queries.
    if (UI.FILTER_CONTACTS_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        mSearchMode = true;
        mShowSearchSnippets = true;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mInitialFilter = extras.getString(UI.FILTER_TEXT_EXTRA_KEY);
            String originalAction =
                    extras.getString(ContactsSearchManager.ORIGINAL_ACTION_EXTRA_KEY);
            if (originalAction != null) {
                action = originalAction;
            }
            String originalComponent =
                    extras.getString(ContactsSearchManager.ORIGINAL_COMPONENT_EXTRA_KEY);
            if (originalComponent != null) {
                component = originalComponent;
            }
        } else {
            mInitialFilter = null;
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Called with action: " + action);
    mMode = MODE_UNKNOWN;
    if (UI.LIST_DEFAULT.equals(action) || UI.FILTER_CONTACTS_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        ..... 
        else if (Intent.ACTION_PICK.equals(action)) {
        // XXX These should be showing the data from the URI given in
        // the Intent.
        final String type = intent.resolveType(this);
        if (Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_PICK_CONTACT;
        } else if (People.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_LEGACY_PICK_PERSON;
        } else if (Phone.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_PICK_PHONE;
        } else if (Phones.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_LEGACY_PICK_PHONE;
        } else if (StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_PICK_POSTAL;
        } else if (ContactMethods.CONTENT_POSTAL_TYPE.equals(type)) {
            mMode = MODE_LEGACY_PICK_POSTAL;
        }
       ....
       // VERY LONG IF WITH DIFFERENT MODE-SELECTION
       ....
    }
    .....
    if (mMode == MODE_JOIN_CONTACT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_content_join);
    } else if (mSearchMode) {
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_search_content);
    } else if (mSearchResultsMode) {
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_search_results);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_content);
    }

    setupListView();
    ...
}
```

It's very long method (and I also suggest to check [`setupListView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.7_r1/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java#ContactsListActivity.setupListView%28%29) method), but pretty straightforward. And, as you can see, **there's no parameter you can pass to specify source of contacts you want to pick from**. Only thing you can configure here is the particular `mMode` ContactsApp to use (`MODE_PICK_CONTACT`, `MODE_PICK_PHONE`, etc.) - but unfortunately number of possible modes is very limited by 6 and non of them suits you.

(If anyone needs to pass `mMode` to `ContanctsListActivity` - use intent's `setType()` method, for example: `intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);`)

#### Workaround

As a workaround - as *tiny sunlight*'s suggested in comments - render non-SIM contacts within the app and pick the one you needed from there.
[How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim/4409453#4409453) - this link looks like most promising one explaining how to query cursor with all contacts, apart from SIM ones.

I hope, it helps